# VBA User Form Initialization Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

Something strange is happening where I call a userform to show via a module, but it says object is required and does not initialize the form. The strange part is the method of calling does not change from a workbook that functions the exact same.

I have a module with the following code assigned to a button:

```
Sub SHOW_INSERT_TASK_FORM()

INSERT_TASK_FORM.Show ' Error Occurs here

End Sub
```

This should initialize the "INSERT_TASK_FORM" user form and run its code but I receive an object required error upon the "Show" method.

Here is the code imbedded within the user form:

```
Private Sub SUBMIT_BUTTON_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


'DECLARE OBJECT VARIABLES
Dim planner_ws As Worksheet, data_ws As Worksheet
Dim departments As ListObject
Dim types As ListObject
Dim tasks As ListObject
Dim dep_arr() As Variant
Dim type_arr() As Variant
Dim task_arr() As Variant
Dim i As Double, j As Double, x As Double
Dim lrow As Double, srow As Double

'SET WS VARIABLES
Set planner_ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TASK_PLANNER")
Set data_ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

'ASSIGN OBJECT VARIABLES
Set departments = data_ws.ListObjects("DEPARTMENT_TABLE")
Set types = data_ws.ListObjects("TASK_TYPE_TABLE")
Set tasks = data_ws.ListObjects("TASKS_TABLE")

'ASSIGN VARIABLE VALUES
dep_arr = departments.DataBodyRange
type_arr = types.DataBodyRange
task_arr = tasks.DataBodyRange
lrow = planner_ws.Cells(planner_ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'INITIAL USER FORM VALUES
TASK_NAME_TBOX.Value = ""
DESC_TBOX.Value = ""
SDATE_TBOX.Value = ""
EDATE_TBOX.Value = ""

Task_Option = False
Sub_Option = False

'POPULATE COMBO BOXES
With TYPE_CBOX
    For i = LBound(type_arr) To UBound(type_arr)
        .AddItem type_arr(i, types.ListColumns("Task_Type").Index)
    Next i
End With

With DEP_CBOX
    For i = LBound(dep_arr) To UBound(dep_arr)
        .AddItem dep_arr(i, types.ListColumns("Department").Index)
    Next i
End With

With TASK_CBOX
    For i = LBound(task_arr) To UBound(task_arr)
        .AddItem task_arr(i, types.ListColumns("Task Name").Index)
    Next i
End With

End Sub

Private Sub SUB_OPTION_Click()
    If Sub_Option.Value = True Then
        Task_Label.Visible = True
        TASK_CBOX.Visible = True
    Else
        Task_Label.Visible = False
        TASK_CBOX.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

For reference, the following code in another workbook of mine works just fine:

```
Sub GameSale_Form()

xInput_GameSale.Show

End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    LCS_Option = False
    NOTLCS_Option = False
    
    Qty_TextBox.Value = ""
    Discount_TextBox.Value = ""
    InputCost_Textbox.Value = ""
    
    InRegion_Option.Value = False
    NotInRegion_Option = False
    
    New_Option.Value = False
    Used_Option.Value = False
    
    InputCost_Option = False
    AvCost_Option = False
    
    FDAPricing_Option = False
    NoFDAPricing_Option = False
    
    With Cabinet_Combobox
        For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 36).End(xlUp).Row
            .AddItem ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Data").Cells(i, 36).Value
        Next i
    End With
    
    Opening_Textbox.Value = ""
    Ambition_Textbox.Value = ""
    Goal_Textbox.Value = ""
    WalkAway_Textbox.Value = ""
    
    Qty_SpinButton.Min = 0
    Qty_SpinButton.Max = 1000
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: @rory.ap INSERT_TASK_FORM.Show

Comment: In the .AddItem lines, you are using column indexes from the types table in your other tables/arrays. Change types for the according table object

Comment: Also, you are doing many unneccessary steps, like creating an array when you could be referencing the cell values directly with .cells(row, col).

Comment: @cyberponk That was it. thanks. Ill look into the more efficient references

Comment: Make sure your VBA error handling option is set to "Break in class module" so you can debug errors in your userforms.